# shell script error

Tags: linux, shell, character-encoding

I have the following line in a shell script:

```
if [ -f /etc/init.d/tomcat6 && ps -C java|grep -qs 'java' ]; then
```

which throws up the following error when I try to run it:

```
line 12: [: missing `]'
```

I have a feeling that this is an encoding issue as I've been editing the file in Notepadd++ on a windows xp pc, I've ensured I've set the encoding to encode in UTF-8 without BOM and that all the line endings are linux style yet I still receive this error.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if [ -f /etc/init.d/tomcat6 ] && ps -C java | grep -qs 'java'; then
    ...
fi
```

`[` is basically an alias for the `test` command. `test` does not know anything about an argument `ps`. Alternatively you may use `test` explicitely (just to clarify syntax):

```
if test -f /etc/init.d/tomcat6  && ps -C java | grep -qs 'java'; then
    ...
fi
```

If you use `[` instead of `test`, you are forced to end the expression with `]`.

Comment: Except `ps` is never actually passed to `[`.

Comment: [ expects its last argument to be ']', and the syntax error is that it is not.  The shell invokes 3 commands: "[ -f /etc/init.d/tomcat6" and "ps -C java" and "grep -qs 'java' ]"...except that it does not actually invoke the second two because the first one fails (so you don't get an error from grep about the file ']' not existing.)

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` ends your `[` command.

```
if [ -f /etc/init.d/tomcat6 ] && ps -C java | grep -qs 'java'; then
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for *and* is `-a`.

You need to run `ps -C java|grep -qs 'java'`, it is currently evaluated as an expression. Try this:

```
if [ -f /etc/init.d/tomcat6 -a $(ps -C java|grep -qs 'java') ]; then
```